# How to create a one-time rake task that moves a folder in an Amazon S3 bucket?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an Amazon S3 bucket that I have many documents uploading too, in two folders, 'Random Folder' & 'Archive'. I would like to place the 'Random Folder' inside of the 'Archive' folder, I have changed the path in the Settings.yml from `path: ':document_folder_name/:filename'`to `path: 'archive/:document_folder_name/:filename'`.

I would like to create a one time rake task, that pulls all documents now within 'Random Folder' into my 'Archive Folder', and have constructed it as follows.

```
 - module Courts   class SyncronizeBucketJob < ApplicationJob
       SRC_FOLDER = 'ocr_scanner'.freeze
       ARCHIVE_FOLDER = 'archive'.freeze
       DATUM_FOLDER = '13.08.2021'.freeze
   
       def perform
         s3_objects = pull_s3_files
         create_ocr_documents(s3_objects)
         delete_s3_objects(s3_objects)
       end
   
       private
   
       def pull_s3_files
         # read files from the folder 'ocr_scanner'
         s3_resource
           .bucket(bucket_name)
           .objects(prefix: SRC_FOLDER)
           .select { |obj| obj.key.ends_with?('.pdf') }
       end
   
       def create_ocr_documents(s3_objects)
         s3_objects.each do |obj|
           resp = s3_client.get_object(bucket: bucket_name, key: obj.key)
           file = resp.body
           OcrDocument.create(document: file)
         end
       end
   
       def remove_s3_objects(s3_objects)
         s3_objects.each(&:delete)
       end
   
       def delete_s3_objects(s3_objects)
         s3_objects.each do |obj|
           new_key = obj.key.sub(SRC_FOLDER, ARCHIVE_FOLDER)
           obj.put(metadata: { 'new_key' => 'ok' })
           obj.move_to(bucket: bucket_name, key: new_key)
         end
       end
```

And my rake file as follows

```
 namespace :courts do
  task update_ocr_documents: :environment do
    OcrDocument.find_each do |ocr_document|
      ::Courts::Operations::OcrDocuments::RecognizeExisting.run(id: ocr_document.id, skip_auth: true)
    end
  end

  task sync_ocr_bucket: :environment do
    ::Courts::SyncronizeBucketJob.perform_now
  end

  task move_ocr_documents: :environment do
    s3_objects.each do |obj|
      new_key = obj.key.sub(SRC_FOLDER, ARCHIVE_FOLDER)
      obj.put(metadata: { 'new_key' => 'ok' })
      obj.move_to(bucket: bucket_name, key: new_key)
    end
  end
end
```

When I attempt to run the rake, I receive this error

```
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'courts:move_ocr_documents' (See the list of available tasks with `rake --tasks`)
Did you mean?  courts:sync_documents
               courts:update_ocr_documents
/Users/co/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-13.0.3/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/co/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval'
/Users/co/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

When I change 'delete S3 Objects' to match with the rake task (as needed?) I then receive this error.

```
rake courts:delete_s3_objects --trace
** Invoke courts:delete_s3_objects (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute courts:delete_s3_objects
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `delete_s3_objects' for Courts::SyncronizeBucketJob:Class
```

Comment: I don't see `courts:sync_documents` in your rake file either.  Do you have multiple rake files with similar tasks or have you deployed the latest version where you are running it?

Comment: @dbugger Yes it's a very large project, but these files linked are the only relevant/worked on files.

Comment: It's difficult to know everything that's going on since it looks like there are other classes in use here that are defined elsewhere in the project, but the error you're seeing is due to no method called `delete_s3_objects ` being defined on the `Courts::SyncronizeBucketJob` class. You could try moving the method definitions to the class level instead (e.g. `def self.delete_s3_objects`)